# Read multiple csv files from multiple folders in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, import, concatenation

I have a folder that includes folders and these folders include many csv files. I want to import and concatenate all of them in Python.

Let's say main folder: /main

subfolders: /main/main_1

csv: /main/main_1/first.csv

```
path='/main'
df_list = [] 
for file in os.listdir(path): 
    df = pd.read_csv(file) 
    df_list.append(df) 

final_df = df.append(df for df in df_list)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific. We know what you want to do, but what have you tried, what happened, and what do you not understand? We will not write your code for you

Comment: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main_1' error occurs. I thought there should be a more practical way for it.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

directory = "path/to/root_dir"

# Read each CSV file in dir "path/to/root_dir"
dfs = []
for file in Path(directory).glob("**/*.csv"):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file))

# Put the dataframes to a single dataframe
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Change the `path/to/root_dir` to where ever your CSV files are.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to concat all of them but it doesn't satisfy to me as it takes too much time due to computational complexity.

```
path = "/main"

folders = []
directory = os.path.join(path)
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    folders.append(root)

del folders[0]


final = []
for folder in folders:
    df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join(folder + "/*.csv"))))
    final.append(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to add back main to the path:

`df =pd.read_csv(path + "/" + file)`

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'main/main_1' occurs. I guess, we just reach the subfolder for now. I will try to import and concat all csv files from the subfolders now.

Comment: You should use 2 nested loops, one to loop through the folders and one to loop through files. You can't open a folder as a file